# How to use order in alphanumerics with only numeric sorting

Tags: c#, linq, model-view-controller, linq-to-entities, sql-order-by

I have the following query:

```
var studentDetail = details.Select(s => 
new {
    StudentId = s.StudentID,
    FirstName = s.FirstName,
    MiddleName = s.MiddleName,
    LastName = s.Lastname,
    RollNumber = s.StudentRollNoDetails.Select(k => k.RollNo).FirstOrDefault(),
    AdmissionNumber = s.AdmissionNo,
    ModifiedON = s.ModifiedOn,
    IsAssigned = s.StudentActivityMappings.Where(k => k.StudentID == s.StudentID && k.CurriculamActivityID == ActivityID)
       .Select(k = k.IsAssigned)
       .FirstOrDefault()
})
.OrderBy(q => Convert.ToInt32(q.RollNumber))
.ToList();
```

How do I use order in alphanumerics with only numeric sorting?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Its not quite clear what you are asking. What do you want this to return? do you have any example data?

Comment: How does your `RollNumber` data look like ? Could you share some sample data

Comment: What does roll number look like, what datatype is it? Show some examples. This is not how you ask questions here or anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Because of your question, I asume, that RollNumber is a string? So instead of 2, 23, 3, 4 you want to have 2, 3, 4, 23?

You can achieve this to parse `StudentRoll` to `int`. For example:

`randoList = randoList.OrderBy(s => int.Parse(s.StudentRoll)).ToList();`